# Is there a way of assigning a label/text to a numeric API result in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am currently using SlideDeck and reporting the viewed slide number to be reported in Google Analytics. What I'm wondering (and honestly have no idea if possible) is whether if the slide deck API reports a specific number, I can assign a label/text to it?

The code I'm using is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nextSlide').click(function() {
     $('.slidedeck').slidedeck().next({
        before: function(deck){
        // do nothing
        },
        complete: function(deck){
          var slideNumber = deck.current != null ? deck.current + ' - ' : '';
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slidedeck', 'viewed slides', slideNumber + 'slide number']);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

This successfully reports the following to Google Analytics:
'slidedeck' (category), 'viewed slides' (label), '1 - slide number' (value, assuming slide 1 is being shown).

What I want to do is assign a name to the result 1, 2, 3 etc..

So in my head (and this is completely not the code as I have no clue how to approach this, but to demonstrate the kind of result:

```
   var slideNumber = deck.current != null ? deck.current + ' - ' : '';
      if($(this).val() == '1'){ //function to report code as '1 - title example'}
});
      if($(this).val() == '2'){ //function to report code as '2 - title example'}
});
```

So the GA event tracking code would be:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slidedeck', 'viewed slides', slideNumber + 'was viewed']);
```

which submits an Event with the following label, assuming slide 1 is viewed:

'slidedeck' (category), 'viewed slides' (label), '1 - title example - was viewed'

I appreciate I'm being vague, and asking a lot - but if anyone can even steer me in the right direction or point me to the functions I'd need to look into, that'd be awesome.

**EDIT:**

I've added this code to the script nnnnnn:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
              var slideTitles = [ "Slide 0 title here",
                                  "Slide 1 title here",
                                  "Slide 2 title here"
                                ]; 
    $('#next').click(function() {
            $('.slidedeck').slidedeck().next({
        before: function(deck){
        // do nothing
        },
        complete: function(deck){
            var slideNumber = deck.current != null ? deck.current + ' - ' : ''; 
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slidedeck', 'viewed slides', slideTitles[slideNumber] + 'was viewed']);
        }
      });

});
```

But I get the following Event Label in Google Analytics: 'undefinedwas viewed'.

What I don't get (as I'm new to jQuery!) is how the response from:

```
complete: function(deck){
          var slideNumber = deck.current != null ? deck.current + ' - ' : '';
```

binds to the array titles?

the deck.current is an API response from the slidedeck plugin, just giving the numeric value of the currently viewed slide.

Sorry to be a pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the titles in an array where the array indexes are (obviously) the slide numbers:

```
var slideTitles = [ "Slide 0 title here",
                    "Slide 1 title here",
                    "Slide 2 title here",
                    ... ];
```

(If there's no slide 0 just put an empty string as a placeholder so that the other indexes correspond to the right titles.)

Then in your existing code given a `slideNumber` just say `slideTitles[slideNumber]` to get the corresponding title.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply nnnnnn, when you say: You can put the titles in an array where the array indexes are (obviously) the slide numbers, is this in the array indexes that slidedeck.js produces? As I can't edit that JS file.

Comment: You can declare that array within your own code, e.g., inside your document.ready function but outside your click function - that way it only gets created once (per page load) and is accessible from within your click function . The titles are titles that you are supplying to go with your own slides, right?

Comment: I get the result undefined now, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong - sorry! I've edited the original post to show the code I'm using. Thank you for taking the time to post and reply above.

Comment: The problem is that the way you're using `slideNumber` it isn't actually a number, it's a string. The index into the `slideTitles` array needs to be a number. I'm not sure in what circumstances `deck.current` could be `null`, but assuming it is normally a number you can say `slideTitles[deck.current]`.

Comment: You're an absolute legend. using slideTitles[deck.current] with your var slideTitles works perfectly!!! Thank you.